# Letter Count on a string

Tags: python

Python newb here. I m trying to count the number of letter "a"s in a given string. Code is below. It keeps returning 1 instead 3 in string "banana". Any input appreciated.

```
def count_letters(word, char):
    count = 0
    while count <= len(word):
        for char in word:
            if char == word[count]:
                count += 1
            return count



print count_letters('banana','a')
```

Comment: I think your code was indented correctly. You would have gotten an indentation error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The other answers show what's wrong with your code. But there's also a built-in way to do this, if you weren't just doing this for an exercise:

```
>>> 'banana'.count('a')
3
```

---

Danben gave this corrected version:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    if char == c:
      count += 1
  return count
```

Here are some other ways to do it, hopefully they will teach you more about Python!

Similar, but shorter `for` loop. Exploits the fact that booleans can turn into 1 if true and 0 if false:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    count += (char == c)
  return count
```

Short for loops can generally be turned into list/generator comprehensions. This creates a list of integers corresponding to each letter, with 0 if the letter doesn't match `char` and 1 if it does, and then sums them:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  return sum(char == c for c in word)
```

The next one filters out all the characters that don't match `char`, and counts how many are left:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  return len([c for c in word if c == char])
```

Comment: Thank you but yeah i m trying to get my head around the concept.

Comment: you don't need `int()` around boolean value in Python: `True == 1 and False == 0` http://ideone.com/k4QLc http://ideone.com/5dHkK

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: very interesting! never knew that. edited to reflect that

Comment: Here's another variant `sum(1 for x in iterable if x == value)`. It can be useful if the iterable has no `count()` method.

Comment: I notice that 'banana'.count('ana') returns 1, rather than 2 as you might expect.

Comment: @user18197: i would only expect 1. `.count()` counts non-overlapping instances only

Answer (score 12):

One problem is that you are using `count` to refer both to the position in the word that you are checking, and the number of `char` you have seen, and you are using `char` to refer both to the input character you are checking, and the current character in the string.  Use separate variables instead.

Also, move the `return` statement outside the loop; otherwise you will always return after checking the first character.

Finally, you only need one loop to iterate over the string.  Get rid of the outer `while` loop and you will not need to track the position in the string.

Taking these suggestions, your code would look like this:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    if char == c:
      count += 1
  return count
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple way is as follows:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
    return word.count(char)
```

Or, there's another way count each element directly:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter('banana')
```

Of course, you can specify one element, e.g.

```
Counter('banana')['a']
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `return` is in your for loop!  Be careful with indentation, you want the line `return count` to be outside the loop.  Because the for loop goes through all characters in `word`, the outer while loop is completely unneeded.

A cleaned-up version:

```
def count_letters(word, to_find):
    count = 0
    for char in word:
        if char == to_find:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of problems:

- There's a problem with your indentation as others already pointed out.
- There's no need to have nested loops. Just one loop is enough.
- You're using char to mean two different things, but the char variable in the for loop will overwrite the data from the parameter.

This code fixes all these errors:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
    count = 0
    for c in word:
        if char == c:
            count += 1
    return count
```

A much more concise way to write this is to use a generator expression:

```
def count_letters(word, char):
    return sum(char == c for c in word)
```

Or just use the built-in method [count](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) that does this for you:

```
print 'abcbac'.count('c')
```

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things wrong.

1. You reuse the identifier `char`, so that will cause issues.
2. You're saying `if char == word[count]` instead of `word[some index]`
3. You return after the first iteration of the for loop!

You don't even need the `while`. If you rename the char param to `search`,

```
for char in word:
    if char == search:
        count += 1
return count
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively You can use:

```
mystring = 'banana'
number = mystring.count('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count_letters=""

number=count_letters.count("")

print number
```

Answer (score 1):

`"banana".count("ana")` returns 1 instead of 2 !

I think the method iterates over the string (or the list) with a step equal to the length of the substring so it doesn't see this kind of stuff.

So if you want a "full count" you have to implement your own counter with the correct loop of step 1

Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_letter(word, char):
    count = 0
    for char in word:
        if char == word:
            count += 1
    return count        #Your return is inside your for loop
r = count_word("banana", "a")
print r
```

> > > 3

Answer (score 0):

```
x=str(input("insert string"))
c=0
for i in x:
   if 'a' in i:
      c=c+1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following program takes a string as input and output a pandas DataFrame, which represents the letter count.

---

**Sample Input**
hello
**Sample Output**
 char Freq.
0 h  1
1 e  1
2 l  2
3 o  1

```
import pandas as pd

def count_letters(word, char):
    return word.count(char)

text = input()
text_split = text.split()
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i in text_split:
    for j in i:
        counter = count_letters (text, j)
        list1.append(j)
        list2.append(counter)
dictn = dict(zip(list1, list2))
df = pd.DataFrame (dictn.items(), columns = ['char', 'freq.'])
print (df)
```