# Counting letters in a string

Tags: python

I am wondering how to count specific letters in a string. The first thing that popped into my head was the function `len`. Out of curiosity, is there a way to write this code without using built in functions and using `len`?

There is a question asked similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932511/letter-count-on-a-string) and I am having trouble understanding it.

```
def count_letters(word, char):
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    if char == c:
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

What exactly is going on in `if char == c:` and `count += 1`? I understand why the person started with a `for` loop but I don't understand why place an `if` after?

Comment: `char` is the letter you want to count how many times it appears in `word`.

You iterate on the letters of `word` and if it's the letter you want, you add the counter by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` is needed because you only want to count instances of a specific character, `char`. Without it, you would wind up doing `count = count + 1` for every character in the string, so you'd get the full string length, not the amount of specific character you're looking for.

With comments in code:

```
for c in word:            # go through each character in code
    if char == c:         # if the character is the one we're counting
        count = count + 1 # add one to the current count of characters
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand why the `if` is needed now. 

The `count +=1` is needed because the loop needs to be  iterated, correct?

Comment: @Robben, no, `for` does that automatically - the `count` variable keeps track of how many of the letters you're looking for you've found. `count += 1` simply adds one to the count whenever you find the right char.

Comment: Thanks, you've been of great help!

Answer (score 2):

Strings have a built in `count()` method:

```
>>> s = 'aaabbbccc'
>>> s.count('a')
3
>>> s.count('aa')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count *only* for specific char. Meaning that if you have the word "hello" and the letter "l", you want to return 2 because "l" appears 2 times in "hello".

The `if` simply checks if the char is the char you want, if that's the case, you increment the counter by one - `for c in word:` iterates on the chars of `word`.

Python's syntax is very readable and easy to understand, try to speak the code and you'll understand what it does.

Another way to do that is:

```
print len([c for c in word if c == char])
```

Example:

```
[c for c in 'hello world' if c == 'l']
```

Will return:

```
['l', 'l', 'l']
```

Then `len` will return 3.

Comment: Thank you! For `print len([c for c in word if c == char])` I see that `c += 1` is not needed there, why is that? What exactly does `c += 1` do?

Comment: @Robben It's `c = c + 1` (The latter is not supported in Python). `c += 1` is not needed because I create a list contains the letters, then I use `len` on it. Try to print each part to better understand what's going on. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in word:
```

In this statement word will be taken as a list of a string, `c` is each character from that list. That means loop will repeat for each character of the word.

So in this statement `if char == c:` for every character of word will be compare with `char`.

If the statement is true then `count` will increase by 1.

So, As per your question

`if char == c:` compare char with each character of word

and

`count+=1` will increase the value of count by 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **[Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)**?

It states that ANY object with an iterating function can be cycled through, which answers your second question.

Since you don't want to use the `len` function, you can use the **for loop** like in the answer you linked to cycle through the object (the String `word`) looking for the character `char`, recording each time the `char` is found with `count`.

The parameter `char` needs to be found in `word` parameter, and so `c` is just a variable to set to each letter (or character, not all parts of the String may be an alphabetical letter) as it cycles through `word`.

The reason for the `if` statement is so when the cycling variable `c` equals `char`, the block can be executed.  In this particular block, the count is being iterated up (`count = count + 1`), and once the function is done with iterating through the for loop, it will return `count` (how many times `char` was found, effectively counting specific letters in the String as you asked for).

Long-winded but in short, yes, that function you posted will give you a count of how many times the letter is in the word.

Answer (score 0):

## Using collections.Counter

```
>>> word = "Hallelujahhhhh"
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(word)
Counter({'h': 5, 'l': 3, 'a': 2, 'e': 1, 'H': 1, 'j': 1, 'u': 1})
```