# Find amount of times that the chosen letters appear

Tags: python, file-io

I have a script where im reading from a file and taking the first two characters from each word in the line, what i am trying to do is find out which two letters shows up the most often, do i have to convert my output here into a list and do it that way ?

here is what i have

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string
import re
import random
import sys


file = raw_input("Enter path to filename :")

text_file= open(file,'r')
data=text_file.readlines()
firsttwo =[]
lines = []

def first2():
    for line in data:   
    firsttwo = line[:2]
    print firsttwo

print first2()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letter Count on a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932511/letter-count-on-a-string)

Comment: ok but the output from above has the first two letters of each word on a seperate line ( the words in teh file are on a seperate line) so do i have to convert this to a string first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct your initial string use a generator comprehension and `join()`:

```
In [49]: mystring="".join(line[:2] for line in data)
```

This can be solved with the `count()` method of the `str` object:

```
In [50]: mystring="helloworld"

In [51]: mystring.count("o")
Out[51]: 2
```

If you want the most common items use `sorted` and `string.ascii_letters`:

```
In [52]: from string import ascii_letters as letters
In [71]: mystring
Out[71]: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "

In [72]: sorted((mystring.count(l),l) for l in letters)[:-5:-1]
Out[72]: [(23, 'e'), (20, 't'), (17, 'n'), (14, 's')]
```

Comment: thanks , this is great. one question for you. My output is something like aabbccddeeaabbaaaaaa. Its all one string . i presume i need to split it into sections of 2 characters so i can then count the number of occureences?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it solves your problem? The last line that starts with `In[53]` answers what you just asked.

Comment: I think you need to accept again, it didn't log it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` that counts the appearances of a item in a list.

```
from collections import Counter

text_file= open("C:/test.txt",'r')
firsttwo = [line[:2] for line in text_file.readlines()]

print Counter(firsttwo)
```

If the content of `test.txt` is:

```
first line
second line
second line
third line
```

The output of the code provied would be:

```
Counter({'se': 2, 'fi': 1, 'th': 1})
```

If you want to convert this output to a list, you can do:

```
list(Counter(firsttwo).items())
```

This outputs:

```
[('fi', 1), ('th', 1), ('se', 2)]
```

**EDIT (without collections):**

```
text_file= open("C:/test.txt",'r')
firsttwo = [line[:2] for line in text_file.readlines()]
l_items = set(firsttwo) 
l_counts = [(firsttwo.count(x), x) for x in set(firsttwo)]
l_counts.sort(reverse=True)
print l_counts[0][1]
```

Comment: cant use "from collections " im afraid

Comment: not really what i was looking for. this just puts a count number beside each one. I need to find which set of 2 letters appear most often in the output

Comment: Updated answer (last line) to fit your desired output.

Comment: thats giving me an output of just one letter from the two .  gives the first letter on some words and second on others

Comment: That outputs what you said "*I need to find which set of 2 letters appear most often in the output*". If the most repated set is `se` that outputs `se`.

Comment: apologies , thats my fault for not being clear. lets saying the output is this aa bb cc dd aa bb cc   (all in a list under each other) . i need to detect that aa appeared the most times

Comment: Why? `aa` appears two times, `bb` appears two times, and `cc` appears also two times.

Comment: :-) . lets say aa appears more than the rest. i need to say aa appears the most

Comment: With the code I gave you outputs the item that appears the most. Where's the problem? If the most repatead par is `aa` it outputs `aa`. It gives what you are asking. Have you tried my *exact* code?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it:

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter

my_file = open("text.txt", 'r')
lines_from_file = my_file.readlines()
first_two_letters = " ".join(item[:2].upper() for item in re.findall("\w+", str(lines_from_file)))

processed_letters = first_two_letters.split()

resulting_count = collections.Counter(processed_letters)

print resulting_count
```

It might not be the best way, but:

- it's reading the file
- stores the first two letters of each word
- using `collections` counter it will count each group of letters