# Python: Counting how many letters are in String

Tags: python, passwords, letters

I am trying to write a basic password checking program and whenever the user has used two attempts to entering the correct password I am supposed to print a hint as to how many letters are in their password. 
Password is the variable that I stored the correct string in.

```
elif attempts == 1:
        letters = 0 
        for i in password:
            if password[i].isaplha():
                letters = letters + 1
        print('There are',letters,'letters in your password')
```

My code gives the error

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-c967c81bda5f> in <module>()
       letters = 0
       for i in password:
---->      if password[i].isaplha():
               letters = letters + 1
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with it? Give a [mcve] we can actually test with an input and expected and actual output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letter Count on a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932511/letter-count-on-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Two issues here.

- `for i in password` is iterating over the actual *characters* in `password` and not their indices, so you should be checking `i.isalpha()`.
- The string method is not `isaplha`, it is `isalpha`.

Fixing these while maintaining your current approach,

```
... 
elif attempts == 1:
    letters = 0 
    for i in password:
        if i.isalpha():
            letters = letters + 1
    print('There are',letters,'letters in your password')
```

and if you wanted to do so a bit more concisely, you could `sum` a generator of booleans based on whether each character `isalpha` or not, using the fact that `True` is `1` in Python.

```
... 
elif attempts == 1:
    letters = sum(i.isalpha() for i in password)
    print('There are {0} letters in your password'.format(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

IsAplha() method return true if you have only alphabetic characters in your string , it does not tell the length of the string, you can do this like 
 print('you have',len(password),'letters in password')

Comment: The OP doesn't want the length of the strings, but the number of *letters* in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve this as well.

```
import re
password = 'hE1Ar'
lett_count = len(re.findall('[A-z]', password))
```

**Update/Correction:**

```
lett_count = len(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', password))
```

Comment: Try `password = 'you_fail'`.